# Lookup field by tag

Tags: go

Consider the following struct

```golang
type Test struct {
  A string `t1:"x"`,
  B string `t1:"y"`,
}
```

Using the reflect package, is there any way for me to get "A" if I know that `t1` tag has value "x"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using the reflect package, is there any way for me to get "A" if I know that t1 tag has value "x"?

Not a direct one.

You must iterate over all fields and check if the field has the appropriate tag.
(Note that two fields may have the same tag, so looking up by tag would not really work.)